# Query language for DDD repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

Currently I am working toward splitting monolith REST api into microservices. I would like to introduce `Domain Driven Design` (currently learning). My biggest concern at this moment is implementing `Repository`.

Domain UBIQUITOUS LANGUAGE defines `Profile` entity (Social media profile e.g Twitter profile). I am thinking to extract `Profile` in to separate microservice. To query profiles i would introduce `ProfileRepository`.

Other microservices including API gateway have their own `Profile` search patterns. How should I design Repository to meet all those search patterns. Should I create `find` method for every query? Should I introduce some sort of dynamic query language?

In a monolith architecture I could create multiple repositories. One for each use case. In microservices architecture I would need to change microservice responsible for `Profile` every time other microservices needs new query.

Comment: There's nothing perfect. If your query mechanisms is too abstract it will be flexible, but very hard to optimize for performance. On the other hand, if your queries are all very explicit then the coupling might be too strong between micro-services. I think that an approach you could consider is to use a message-based infrastructure to duplicate the information needed to process queries in every other micro-services. If that is not suitable then you will have to try to strike a good balance between flexibility, performance and explicitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dynamic query language will introduce another level of complexity my personal opinion is that you should avoid this unless you really, really need it - i.e. when other people are going to integrate your system a lot. I strongly agree with @plalx 's comment to your post - adding complexity always has its price and that goes both ways.

On the ubiquitous language & terminology mix - you should really avoid duplicate terms in your domain. The "Profile" concerning a social media account could be named "SocialProfile". So when a "Profile" means two different things in two different contexts: try to find a better term for one of those. Sure you can know that a 'Profile' in the context of 'API gateway' is something and at the same time it is something else in that other context however this will not do you good in the long term - try adding new people to the project and explaining how many different things you call 'a Profile'.

On your last question:

> In a monolith architecture I could create multiple repositories. One for each use case. In microservices architecture I would need to change microservice responsible for Profile every time other microservices needs new query.

It really depends on your architecture - do your micro-services use the same code-base & Repository classes? Are they even in the same name-space? You could have one Repository for each micro-service to use and that is the logical approach since your different micro-services will do different things.
If you take my advice and find concrete terms for each Entity in your Domain you will not have to wonder around this. :)

And a side-note on REST APIs from my practice:
  If your API is truly REST you can just use Repositories behind each endpoint. However if you find your API endpoints are not just reading & returning data (or entities) but also 'doing something' then there are 2 things to note:
 - your API is most-probably not REST but plain RPC
 - the objects you use behind endpoints are most-likely Services and not Repositories

Comment: I agree with your first statement about naming Profile to SocialProfile. I try not to share the same code base among microservices. Every microservice has its own source repository. It allows for me to introduce other utility microservices without changing others. My goal is to access database for SocialProfile in a single microservice. Other microservices would use its API to access SocialProfiles.